# Calling a class function from within another function

Tags: ios, objective-c

This sounds ridiculous but its not working. Can someone see what I am missing?

I have a ViewController in which I defined a function called ProcessData. I am trying to call ProcessData from the viewDidLoad function but it does not see it. I declared it in the .h file and then defined it in the .m file. Here is the code.

ViewController.h
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController

```
- (void) ProcessData: (NSString *)response;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [ProcessData nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) ProcessData: (NSString *)response
{

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a class / static function you have to write

```
[ViewController ProcessData: nil];
```

you have to call the method `ProcessData` on the class `ViewController`.

**But** what you have here is not a class / static method since it is `- (void)` instead of `+ (void)`. Your mistake is basically using the wrong syntax for calling any method. You call methods on objects like

```
[self ProcessData: nil];
```

instead of

```
[ProcessData: nil];
```

**Final Note**: method names should start with a lower character! The method should be called `processData`!

Comment: Thanks! I come from c and c++ and so am not quite there in terms of obj-c thinking.

Comment: @user220201 note that you can still create normal c-functions and call them like you would call regular c-function if you ever want to. Obj-C is a superset of C

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you haven't declared a class method, you've declared an instance method, so you'd call it by doing:

```
[self ProcessResponse: nil];
```

If you want to declare a class function, you need to use a `+` at the start if the declaration instead of a `-`:

```
+ (void) ProcessResponse: (NSString *)response;
```

You'd call this like this:

```
[ViewController ProcessResponse: nil];
```

As a side note, you should actually follow common convention by formatting like this:

```
+ (void)processResponse:(NSString *)response;
```

Note pascal case (no capital at the start of the method name), no space between return type and name, and no space between method name and the parameter type.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a class method. It's a instance method. You have to call it like this:

```
[self ProcessResponse:nil];
```

Class method is defined with "plus" symbol (+), not a hyphen (-).

And method name should start with lowercase.